# What does a Graphics object actually represents?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, buffer

Ok, I'm not even sure if that is the right question to ask.
I've been confused by what is A Graphics object for a while now, I used to think that it is simplly a tool to use to change colors and draw to specific container(ie JFrame, JPanel).
However, I've been studying buffering(triple, double, flipping...etc) and how it works for 3 days now, and my confusion has only increased. for instance, why when we need to draw to the buffer(ie BufferStrategy, BufferedImage) we get its own graphics object to draw to it and then we project it to the screen? does the Graphics Object represent the drawing surface (ie the JPanel it self if we're using one to draw custom painting via `JPanel#paintComponent(Graphics g)`) ? 
and so when we're getting the graphics object of a buffer, do we actually get its drawing surface to paint on?
Please somebody explain, any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: -1, Crossposted: http://www.coderanch.com/t/638069/GUI/java/Graphics-object-represents

Comment: wow, you guys are very good when it comes to taking points away, but not so good when it comes to actually answering the question

Comment: The question was answered. It is annoying to waste time answering a question in one forum only to find out it has been asked/answered in another forum. I would rather spend my time helping someone who appreciates my effort. You haven't even bother to reply to the help you received in the other forum. Why don't you actually spend some time trying to answer questions instead of asking them all the time before making comments!

Comment: the question was not answered in full. I only asked on the other forum  because i didn't get the full answer here. and if I have a question i will seek the answer EVERYWHERE, here,  code ranch, dream in ode, yahoo answers, ask my mother...etc.

Comment: @user3929076 We understand that you want to use as many resources as possible. But since it's a human (doing this for free in their spare time) on the other end, you can at least make it easier on us by linking to all of the other places you've posted, that way we don't waste our time answering questions that already have answers. Do you really value our time so little that you can't copy some links into your post? And if so, why should we care about yours? Your selfish attitude won't get you very far, and it requires no extra work from you to just post the links.

Answer (score 1):

From the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/):

> A Graphics object encapsulates state information needed for the basic
>   rendering operations that Java supports. This state information
>   includes the following properties:
>
> - The Component object on which to draw.
> - A translation origin for rendering and clipping coordinates.
> - The current clip.
> - The current color.
> - The current font.
> - The current logical pixel operation function (XOR or Paint).
> - The current XOR alternation color (see setXORMode(java.awt.Color)).

So a Graphics instance contains information about **WHERE** to draw (a component) as well as **HOW** to draw it (a color, font, etc). It then gives you methods so you can tell it **WHAT** to draw (a rectangle, circle, text, etc).

Comment: "WHERE to draw (a component)" so when we say `bufferedimage#creategraphics` it's like where getting the location to which we well do any drawing using that same Graphics object. tell me if i'm getting warmer here

Comment: so if we are using a JPanel and we say `bufferedImage#createGraphics` and use that graphics object to draw to, we would not be drawing to the JPanel but to the `BufferedImage` correct?

Comment: Correct. But it would probably be more effective for you to create an example program that tested your theories instead.